# mysql Query performance is low

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have a query which is running for around 2 hours in last few days. But 
    before that it took only 2 to 3 minutes of time. i could not able to find 
    the reason for its sudden slowness. Can any one help me on this?
    Please find the below query explain plan[![enter image description here][1]]
    [1]...

```
select
IFNULL(EMAIL,'') as EMAIL,
IFNULL(SITE_CD,'') as SITE_CD,
IFNULL(OPT_TYPE_CD,'') as OPT_TYPE_CD,
IFNULL(OPT_IN_IND,'') as OPT_IN_IND,
IFNULL(EVENT_TSP,'') as EVENT_TSP,
IFNULL(APPLICATION,'') as APPLICATION
from (
SELECT newsletter_entry.email email,
      newsletter.site_cd site_cd,
      REPLACE (newsletter.TYPE, 'OPTIN_','') opt_type_cd,
      CASE
       WHEN newsletter_event_temp.post_status = 'SUBSCRIBED' THEN 'Y'
               WHEN newsletter_event_temp.post_status = 'UNSUBSCRIBED' THEN 
'N'
          ELSE ''
      END
         opt_in_ind,
      newsletter_event_temp.event_date event_tsp,
      entry_context.application application
 FROM amg_toolkit.newsletter_entry,
      amg_toolkit.newsletter,
     (select NEWSLETTER_EVENT.* from amg_toolkit.NEWSLETTER_EVENT, 
amg_toolkit.entry_context where newsletter_event.EVENT_DATE >= '2017-07-11 
00:01:23' AND newsletter_event.EVENT_DATE < '2017-07-11 01:01:23' and 
newsletter_event.ENTRY_CONTEXT_ID = entry_context.ENTRY_CONTEXT_ID and 
entry_context.APPLICATION != 'feedbackloop') newsletter_event_temp,
      amg_toolkit.entry_context
WHERE newsletter_entry.newsletter_id = newsletter.newsletter_id
      AND newsletter_entry.newsletter_entry_id =
             newsletter_event_temp.newsletter_entry_id
      AND newsletter.TYPE IN ('OPTIN_PRIM', 'OPTIN_THRD', 'OPTIN_WRLS')
      AND newsletter_event_temp.entry_context_id NOT IN
             (select  d.ENTRY_CONTEXT_ID from amg_toolkit.sweepstake a, 
amg_toolkit.sweepstake_entry b, amg_toolkit.user_entry c, 
amg_toolkit.entry_context d where  a.exclude_data = 'Y' and 
a.sweepstake_id=b.sweepstake_id and b.USER_ENTRY_ID=c.USER_ENTRY_ID and 
c.ENTRY_CONTEXT_ID = d.ENTRY_CONTEXT_ID)
      AND newsletter_event_temp.entry_context_id =
             entry_context.entry_context_id
      AND newsletter_event_temp.event_date >= '2017-07-11 00:01:23'
      AND newsletter_event_temp.event_date < '2017-07-11 01:01:23') a;`




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgsS1.png
```

Comment: If you don't know a DBA maybe it's time to find one. Either that or cut that query down to size.

Comment: i'm that DBA and i dont know the root cause of this issue. Can you explain me the solution?

Comment: Start deleting things from your query until it's no longer slow, then add things back until you can identify the thing that causes the problem. Same as always. You'll also want to carefully check your index coverage. Any time I see a query this large I know it's going to be bad times in terms of performance. It's very hard to get this kind of monster to be performant.

Answer (score 0):

dont use .*
select only the columns of data you are using in your query.

Avoid nested sub selects if you dont need them.

I don't see a need for them in this query.  You query the data 3 times this way instead of just once.

Slowness can be explained by an inefficient query haveing to deal with tables that have a growing number of records.

"Not in" is resource intensive.  Can you do that in a better way avoiding "not in" logic?

Answer (score 0):

`JOINs` are usually faster than subqueries.  `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` can usually be turned into `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE id IS NULL`.

What is the `a` in `a.exclude_data`?  Looks like a syntax error.

These indexes are likely to help:

```
newsletter_event: INDEX(ENTRY_CONTEXT_ID, EVENT_DATE) -- in this order
```

You also need it for `newsetter_event_temp`, but since that is not possible, something has to give.  What version of MySQL are you running?  Perhaps you could actually `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` and `ADD INDEX`.